# Efficient way to rotate a slice in golang

Tags: go, reverse, micro-optimization

I need a function to efficiently reverse a slice in golang. (My concrete need is to reverse the prefix of a []byte).

I checked the example from [Effective Go](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#for) with `objdump -Sd` and a lot of boiler plate is generated to check for array indexes. Even the swap is too inefficient.

Comment: I managed to disable bounds checking with -B

Comment: @Matt I haven't really experienced any speed issues for anything but contrived examples.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, I have to say it: Profile first. Is this really a bottleneck in your code? If it is, you have a few options.

1) Disable bounds checking. I think there's an undocumented compiler flag that turns of slice bounds checking. I can't find it at the moment though. (EDIT: `-B` according to OP).

2) Write the routine in C (or assembler), you can write C for [586]c and link in your go package (you'll need to include some headers from `$GOROOT/src/pkg/runtime`), like so:

```
#include "runtime.h"
mypackage·swapslice(Slice s) {
    int i, j;
    //Not a real swap loop
    for (i = 0, j = s.len - 1; i < j; i++, j--)
        //swap s.arr[i] and s.arr[j];
}
```

Comment: I didn't test this, but `i < s.len` should be replaced by `i < j`, or the slice will be swapped two times (and thus not at all).

Comment: @Christian I'm not sure this question/answer is really relevant anymore, but you are correct. fixed.